# I want to add a Facebook style messenger to my Ruby on Rails application so Users from the User model can have a conversation with each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So right now I have a basic CRUD app using Devise. I have a User model I generated with it. I want to know what the best way would be to add a messenger component to it similar to Facebooks so users can talk with each other. What would if possible be the best way to accomplish this within Rails?

Comment: I would start with googling the topic and working from there.  SO is really for more specific questions related to a coding issue, not how to build an entire feature.  Something like this *could be a good place to start, which I found googling "ruby on rails real time chat" : https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-app-ruby-rails.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably easily take advantage of [Action Cable](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html), to use existing Rails WebSocket functionality and get it good enough.

If you really want to make it like Facebook, you will need to [use MQTT](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/building-facebook-messenger/10150259350998920). I have no experience with it, but https://github.com/njh/ruby-mqtt purports to be a pure Ruby gem that implements the MQTT protocol.

Comment: Thanks Brad, your response led me to be able to find this tutorial which allows 
users to add a chat application similar to Hangouts to your application thats based on Faye: http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/gmail-like-chat-application-in-ruby-on-rails